# Word "References" with bibtex for Harvard style references iopart document

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

I am creating an iopart document and I need to include the references using Harvard style. 
My problem is that I can't get it to print the word "References" before listing them. I don't know what I am missing, I tried with a different documentclass and this works, but for some reason it is not working with iopart. All of my references are in the .bib file called bibliography_all.bib.

This is an example of my LaTex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{harvard}  
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{dcu.bst}

This is a test
\cite{ACS2017}
\bibliography{bibliography_all}
\end{document}
```

And this is what a get:
[image: The bibliography starts right after the text]

Any help will be really appreciated. I am pretty new to this. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Maybe try to add a unnumbered chapter/section in front of the bibligraphy. `\section*{References}\bibliography{bibliography_all}`?

Comment: If this does not help, can you point us to where `iopart.cls` and `dcu.bst` is available?

Comment: That works! Thank you very much, I should have though about it!

Comment: @samcarter - The `dcu` bibliography style is distributed with the `harvard` citation management package.

Comment: Off-topic: Proper syntax is `\bibliographystyle{dcu}`, *not* `\bibliographystyle{dcu.bst}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a headline for the bibliography simply add it yourself -- for example with

```
\section*{References}
\bibliography{bibliography_all}
```